# Can the fragments be used in android 2.3 project ?

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments

For `fragments` and other newer UI components, Can be used in project that has build `target 2.3` ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there's the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and other projects such as [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)